# Como fazer debounce (consultar apenas depois de terminar de digitar no input) no VUEJS?

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Eu venho do AngularJS e, em determinados momentos, quando preciso fazer uma consulta de acordo com o que o usuário vai pesquisando, eu uso `ng-change`, porém combino ele com `ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}"`. Isso faz com que as consultas do angular não saia disparando consultas igual louco no meu servidor, mas faz com que a pesquisa seja feita apenas quando para de digitar.

Eu queria fazer a mesma coisa com o Vue, porém a opção `debounce` [foi depreciada](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873) na versão 2.0+.

E agora? Como eu poderia fazer em VueJS para poder executar um `@input` apenas quando o usuário para de digitar?

Existe isso no VueJS pronto, ou vou ter que fazer "na mão"?

Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" 
  v-model="pesquisa.nome" 
  @input="consultarSoQuandoPararDeDigitar()" />
```

Comment: No Vue "puro" não tem mais isso pronto, você precisa usar um pacote externo, ou implementar por conta própria. A biblioteca lodash pode ser usada para uma implementação simples. Infelizmente não estou com tempo para postar uma resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto hum... eu já estou até fazendo um esquema que sempre uso com `setTimeOut`. Qualquer coisa, posto aqui, mas vou aguardar uma resposta por enquanto.

Comment: Eu utilizo o https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso usando o [vue-rx](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-rx) que integra o [rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api) ao ciclo de vida dos componentes Vue.

Veja um exemplo funcionando: https://codesandbox.io/s/k011nv98kr

Código fonte do exemplo:

main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRx from "vue-rx";
import App from "./App";

Vue.use(VueRx);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-stream:input="search$"> - debounced: {{ searchedValue }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { debounceTime, pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';

export default {
  name: "App",
  domStreams: ['search$'],
  subscriptions,
  data,
  methods: {
    onSearch
  }
};

function subscriptions() {
  this.search$.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    pluck('event', 'target', 'value')
  ).subscribe(this.onSearch);
}

function data() {
  return {
    searchedValue: null
  }
}

function onSearch(value) {
  this.searchedValue = value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi publicar uma resposta para registrar a forma que resolvi o problema. Eu utilizei uma técnica de debounce para Javascript, baseando-se num `setTimeout`.

Veja:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  methods: {
    consultarQuandoParar: function consultarQuandoParar($event) {
      
      // Se chamar mais de uma vez, cancela a chamada anterior  
      
      console.log('digitou');
      clearTimeout(consultarQuandoParar.timeout);
      
      consultarQuandoParar.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
          console.log('parou de digitar e o resultado é "%s"', $event.target.value);
      }, 500);
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" @input="consultarQuandoParar($event)" />
</div>
```

Basicamente, eu chamo o `clearTimeout` para  cancelar a última chamada de `setTimeout` que é atribuído na propriedade `.timeout`. Se a digitação continua antes de terminar a execução dos `500` milissegundos da chamada anterior, ela é sempre cancelada. Quando para de digitar, a mesma é executada.

Assim, com o `setTimeout` sendo sempre cancelado, permitindo-se executar apenas o "mais recente", temos o efeito do `debounce` para as consultas.